Не проходят некоторые символы из Appsheet в Телеграм, в чем может быть проблема?
В AppSheet создал бота для отправки сообщений в Телеграм, туда в качестве переменной передаются названия материалов из гугл-таблицы.
Заметил, что некоторые названия, которые содержат в тексте знак "минус" или  скобку, в Телеграм не  приходят.
Синтаксис выглядит  так:
HTTP Content Type: JSON
{"chat_id":-10020478ххх,
"text":"<<CONCATENATE("Клей ", text([Название]))>>",
"parse_mode":"MarkdownV2"}

Название типа АБВ проходит, АБВ-1 или АБВ(1) - нет. Отправка чистой переменной или  преобразование в  text() не помогает.
Можно  ли как-то  преобразовать  переменную [Название], чтоб проходили  все символы  без  проблем? Или хотя-бы понять,  это проблема  при отправке из Appsheet или  при приеме
в Телеграм  или  подправить синтаксис сообщения?
